# doubts about foursquare API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, foursquare

My question is not about FourSquare API and its functions, but about more simpler details that are not well explained on Foursquare API explanations. Thank you very much in advance if someone wants to help me with this doubts:

1. Foursquare API is a framework you can use to build applications for mobile devices, above of IOS and Android, so i can imagine that they have API for IOS (Objective-C) and Android (Java), right?
2. From API Doc: "Be sure to note that although API requests are against api.foursquare.com, OAuth token and authorization requests are against foursquare.com.". Does it mean that if i want to use FourSquare app, the users has to have an account on FourSquare?
3. From API Doc: "For example, if you write an iPhone application, every user who logs in with their foursquare account will be able to make up to 500 users/* requests and up to 500 venues/* requests, etc."  I dont understand this sentence. Does it mean that for example, if you use an API method request like "checkins.add()", this method create two methods? one against api.foursquare.com to monitor the API limit requests, and another to your Web Application Server?
4. So as a question related to the third one, where do you have to store your database? is it stored on Foursquare cloud database because you are loggin there, or you have to create your own Web Service application with its own SQL database?
5. From API Doc: "All requests are simple GET or POST requests that return JSON or JSONP respones", so i can imagine that the Web Application Service should understand JSON. Well, my main question is, can i use Ruby on Rails to build the Web Application Service and Web Page frontend? I am seeing that there are some wrapps for RoR designed from third companies, but are not official and doesnt cover all the 2.0 API, just the ones they needed for their services.
6. If i want to create an app using FourSquare API, what do you advice me to use as a programming language/framework for the Web Service Application? the WSA that has to process the JSON requests and later store them on the database, interaction with users on the WebPage, etc.

i am so sorry if my questions are so simple, but i dont have any other place of this level of expertise.

thank you very very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. The API is REST/JSON based, which means that any language that can do an HTTP request and parse a string can be used.  There are Java and iOS libraries available.  But you could use just about anything - curl with bash would be a bit extreme but if that floats your boat...
2. For some of the APIs (search a venue, for example) you do not necessarily need a FourSquar OAuth user token.  For others (like checkin) a FourSquare token is required.  For any API calls that require a userid, your users will have to be FourSquare users and "trust" your application with their FourSquare data.
3. Only requests to FourSquare is counted.  So if you do a single call to checkins.add() it counts as one call for the user that is doing the checkin.  I wouldn't worry about the limits.  As long as you're usage of the API is sensible they will not be a problem.  And if they do become a problem and you're doing something extraordinarily cool, the folks at FourSquare might be sympathetic.
4. You have to create your own web server with your own database to store some information.  The OAuth token is one.  You probably want to cache venue information here for short periods as well.
5. Yes, your webapp will need to be able to understand JSON.  Ruby has excellent JSON support - look for the json gem.
6. It is really difficult to suggest a language or framework without knowing what it is that you're trying to do.  I wouldn't choose a framework based on the fact that you want to use FourSquare (anything will do) but rather on your experience and the unique features of your application.  You mentioned RoR before - that would definitely work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer leonm. You clear all my doubts. thanks again.